# matplotlib two charts side-by-side with third overlying the second chart

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use matplotlib (more specifically the plot method from pandas) to plot two charts side-by-side in an ipython notebook with a third chart overlying the second chart and using a secondary y axis.  However, I have been unable to get the overlay to work.

Currently this is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
fig.set_size_inches(12, 4)

top10.plot(kind='barh', ax=axs[0])
top10_time_trend.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, legend=False, ax=axs[1])
time_trend.plot(kind='line', ax=axs[1], ylim=0, secondary_y=True)
```

I get the side-by-side structure I am looking for, but only the first (top10) and last (time_trend) plots are visible.  My output is below:

[image]

When plotted separately the unshown plot (top10_time_trend) looks like this

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is something that looks like this, i.e. the line chart overlaying the stacked bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best method to do this is by creating a third axis say:

```
ax3 = ax[1].twinx()
```

and then

```
top10_time_trend.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, legend=False, ax=ax3)
```

Please let me know if this works for you.

Here you can find an example for the usage of twinx() from matplotlib docs http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake above. Please make sure you try the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response Francisco! Unfortunately, its still not working. Twinx seems to be what I need, and I can successfully overlay two charts if I make them directly with matplotlib.  However, it doesn't seem to work when the charts are created through pandas. 

Now that I look at my attempt more critically, I'm noticing that I get the two axis that I would expect.  It's almost like the background of the one chart is blocking visibility to the other.